# Trying to retrieve param from JWT

Tags: angularjs, express, jwt

I'm new to using Json Web Tokens and recently implemented an Angular Authorization tutorial for a project, which works well for my authorization needs.

https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-1/

Now I want to decode the JWT on the client side and pull out the user _id in oder to use it as a unique ID for other API calls, but I don't see how to do that.

Does anyone have a good example of pulling and using the information from a JWT with angular?

Here is my auth service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('App')

.service('AuthService', function($q, $http, API_ENDPOINT) {
  var LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY = 'My big secret here';
  var isAuthenticated = false;
  var authToken;

  function loadUserCredentials() {
    var token = window.localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
    if (token) {
      useCredentials(token);
    }
  }

  function storeUserCredentials(token) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY, token);
    useCredentials(token);
  }

  function useCredentials(token) {
    isAuthenticated = true;
    authToken = token;

    // Set the token as header for your requests!
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = authToken;
  }

  function destroyUserCredentials() {
    authToken = undefined;
    isAuthenticated = false;
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = undefined;
    window.localStorage.removeItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
  }

  var register = function(user) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      $http.post(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/signup', user).then(function(result) {
        if (result.data.success) {
          resolve(result.data.msg);
        } else {
          reject(result.data.msg);
        }
      });
    });
  };

  var login = function(user) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      $http.post(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/authenticate', user).then(function(result) {
        if (result.data.success) {
          storeUserCredentials(result.data.token);
          resolve(result.data.msg);
        } else {
          reject(result.data.msg);
        }
      });
    });
  };

  var logout = function() {
    destroyUserCredentials();
  };

  loadUserCredentials();

  return {
    login: login,
    register: register,
    logout: logout,
    isAuthenticated: function() {return isAuthenticated;},
  };
})

.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, AUTH_EVENTS) {
  return {
    responseError: function (response) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast({
        401: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,
      }[response.status], response);
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
})

.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
});
```

My goal is to add a function that parses the token and let's me pull one or more params.

Answer (score 0):

A JWT ([Learn JSON Web Tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/)) allows the data that it contains to be signed and/or encrypted. Given you mention a JWT used for authentication, it's almost certain that the token you receive is just signed. <sub>The premise for this assumption is that if it's not signed you can't trust the information within so it makes no sense to use it for authentication and encrypted tokens are not in widespread usage.</sub>

Additionally, the recommended way to represent the token when used within HTTP environments is to base64url encode the various parts of the token, including the data payload; this means that accessing the data can be easily achieved by applying the necessary base64url decoding and then interpreting the result as JSON. However, in order to trust that data you must validate the signature and make any other validation applicable for your use case.

You can check [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) libraries section to get a list of libraries that are implemented in Javascript and that support working with JWT's.

For example, you could check [Auth0 `angular-jwt`](https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt) library and see the [example on how to decode a token](https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt#decoding-the-token).

---

Finally, you mention you want to pull the user identifier in order to use it in other calls; If the other calls make sensitive decisions based on the received user identifier that does not seem to be secure.